# Andengine Configuration Error For Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, andengine

I'm trying to configure andengine on eclipse. there are some warnings in andengine default folder in src folder. I didn't change anything. I build it with api 15.
How can i fix this? OS : Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment just ignore them.
Unless you use those features on a newer device you won't have any problems. They do usually offer newer alternatives to those Depreciated functions, I suggest you ignore the depreciated warnings that are inside AndEngine and only worry if they are inside your own project. Look into it if you run into a problem with testing.

On the other hand, I have never seen the 'Resource-Leak' that's in the MusicFactory on line 67, maybe you could post the function if you can't fix it yourself. My MusicFactory has been edited too much to tell where the problem would be. For now I'll assume it's the createMusicFromFile function, here's what mine looks like...

```
public static Music createMusicFromFile(final MusicManager pMusicManager, final File pFile) throws IOException {
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pFile);
    final FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = fileInputStream.getFD();
    StreamUtils.close(fileInputStream);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    final Music music = new Music(pMusicManager, mediaPlayer);
    pMusicManager.add(music);

    return music;
}
```

Maybe yours is missing

```
StreamUtils.close(fileInputStream);
```